# Angular + web3.js: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'

Tags: angular, web3js

I'm trying to get started with Angular and Web3.js to work with some Ethereum contracts.  To reproduce:

1. ng new
2. npm install web3 --save
3. ng serve

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ng-eth",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web3": "^1.3.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import Web3 from "web3";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'ngEth';
  
  private window: any;
  
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document)
  {
    this.window = this.document.defaultView;
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    
       if (this.window.ethereum) {
        this.window.web3 = new Web3(this.window.ethereum);
        this.window.ethereum.enable();
        return true;
      }
  }
  
}
```

Error: ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

Error: ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\lib'

Error: ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

Error: ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'

Error: ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

Error: ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'

Error: ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

Error: ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

Error: ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\cipher-base'

Error: ./node_modules/keccak/lib/api/keccak.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\keccak\lib\api'

Error: ./node_modules/keccak/lib/api/shake.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\profile\Documents\projects\ATS\ngEth\ngEth\node_modules\keccak\lib\api'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easist way to make it working is to patch `webpack.config.js` generated by Angular CLI.

### Method 1(no additional dependencies required)

Create `web3-patch.js` file in root folder of your app.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// path can differ depend on Angular CLI version
const browserConfigPath = 'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs/browser.js';

fs.readFile(browserConfigPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  const result = data.replace(/node: false/g, 'node: {crypto: true, stream: true}');

  fs.writeFile(browserConfigPath, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Execute this script on postinstall

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve",
  ...
  "postinstall": "node web3-patch.js"
},
```

### Method 2

Use a module that will allow you to extend Angular CLI: [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus) or [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders)

Execute schematic

```
ng add ngx-build-plus
```

Create **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  node: { crypto: true, stream: true }
};
```

Update **angular.json**

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
    "options": {
      ...
      "styles": [
        "src/styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js" <== add this
    },
    "configurations": {
      ...
  },
  "serve": {
    "builder": "ngx-build-plus:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "cli1125:build",
      "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js" <== add this
    },
    ...
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.  Are there any side effects that come with this?  What's the reason that we have to do this?

Comment: Method 1 saved hours of frustration. Thank you!
Tested on Angular 11, web3 ^1.2.11, typescript ~4.0.2

Comment: Method 1 gives me this error when I run the postinstall: " ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs/browser.js", ng 12.0.2, node 14.1.0

Comment: I got the same error as @Jim. I'm working with Angular 13

Answer (score 16):

In Angular 12, the solution posted by @yurzui doesn't work anymore due to webpack 5 upgrade.

To fix the compilation error you need to install the required dependencies:

```
npm install crypto-browserify stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify os-browserify
```

Then you can use tsconfig paths to point to the required libs:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths" : {
      "crypto": ["./node_modules/crypto-browserify"],
      "stream": ["./node_modules/stream-browserify"],
      "assert": ["./node_modules/assert"],
      "http": ["./node_modules/stream-http"],
      "https": ["./node_modules/https-browserify"],
      "os": ["./node_modules/os-browserify"],
    }
  }
}
```

source: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/4070